# Secured Websockets with Nodejs over Nginx Reverse Proxy - Error 301

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, nginx, websocket

Hi I've been trying to do this previously with Apache with no success. I've decided to try Nginx instead.

I'm trying to establish the following,

client <-- wss -- > Nginx <-- ws --> Nodejs

Seems like a simple thing to do, however I'm not getting any success. I'm continuously getting Error 301.

My **client** side is simple,

```
const connection = new WebSocket('wss://' + location.host + '/ws');
```

Server side is,

```
const ws = new WebSocket.Server({port: 8080});
```

Nginx config file is,

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot                                                                                                                                                                       
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot                                                                                                                                             
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot                                                                                                                                                                        
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot                                                                                                                                                                  

    location / {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    }

    location /ws {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;                                                                                                                   
        proxy_set_header Host $host;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        proxy_http_version 1.1; # Needed                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; # Needed                                                                                                                                                                                             
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade"; # Needed                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }
}
server {
     if ($host = example.com) {                                                                                                                                                                                                              
          return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
     } # managed by Certbot

     listen 80;

     server_name example.com;
     return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I've seen numerous posts regarding the websockets config set up, and the one I have no should definitely work. However, no matter how hard I try it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out,

The problem was that I set up the Websocket to be on port 8080, however my proxy_pass is setup for the port 3000.

The solution was to have them both be on the same port.

For the app server

```
const ws = new WebSocket.Server({port: 3001});
```

and have the Nginx to have the same port under /ws,

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
```